# Counting subsets of a set - how is there a bijection?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

So C⊆A, you define f:A→{0,1} by f(x)=1 if x∈C, f(x)=0 if x∉C. I can't get my head around how there's a bijection between P(A) and Fun(A,{0,1}). Could someone please explain because it's killing me not knowing the answer.

Thank you!

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your question you define a function given a subset. That's a map from $P(A)$ to $\text{Fun}(A, \{0,1\})$. Now show it's a bijection: different subsets of $A$ lead to different functions; every such function comes from a subset.

Comment: Ohhhh I get it now! Didn't read my lecture notes thoroughly. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. There's a lesson there for next time before you ask.

Answer (score 0):

A function $\chi:A\to\{0,1\}$ (that's the Greek letter "chi") is said to be a **characteristic function** of $C\subseteq A$ if $\chi(x)=1$ if $x\in C$ and $\chi(x)=0$ otherwise. Basically, $\chi$ tells us whether any $x\in A$ is an element of the subset $C$. This gives us an injection from $P(A)$ to $\text{Fun}(A, \{0,1\})$, since no two characteristic functions will behave the same unless they are based on the same set.

To find an injection from $\text{Fun}(A,\{0,1\})$ to $P(A)$, the same thing works in reverse. For any $f\in\text{Fun}(A,\{0,1\})$, we can define a set $C=\{a\in A|f(a)=1\}$. Similarly, no two subsets of $A$ defined in this way will be the same unless they are based on the same function.

Since this relation between characteristic functions and subsets of $A$ is injective in both directions, it must be a bijection.

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you very much!